# Roots of characteristic equation reciprocal to roots of its inverse

Tags: time-series, self-study

This is probably just as much an algebra question as a time series question (no homework, self study).

I'm looking to understand why there is a reciprocal relationship between the roots of the *characteristic equation* and the roots of the *inverse characteristic equation* (of a difference equation in a time series context).

More specifically, the n-th order autoregressive difference equation

$$
y_t = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i y_{t-i} + \epsilon_t
$$

can be written with the lag operator $L y_i = y_{i-1}$ as

$$
(1 - a_1 L - \dots - a_n L^n) y_t = a_0 + \epsilon_t\quad.
$$

The roots $\alpha_i$ of the *characteristic equation* (obtained by substituting trial solution $A \alpha^t$ into the homogeneous part of the difference equation)

$$
\alpha^n - a_1 \alpha^{n-1} - \dots - a_n = 0
$$

are the reciprocals $L_i$ of the *inverse characteristic equation*

$$
1 - a_1 L - \dots - a_n L^n = 0
$$

obtained from determining the roots of the lag polynomial above. (This is stated in W. Enders, "Applied Econometric Time Series", 4th edition, p. 42.)

What's a quick way to derive this result?

Comment: This seems to be related to the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#General_properties) of [reciprocal polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial).

Comment: Divide the first equation in $\alpha$ by $\alpha^n$, QED.

Comment: Uh, thanks whuber, that should've actually been quite obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As whuber pointed out in the comments, this is almost trivial:

Dividing the characteristic equation

$$
\alpha^n - a_1 \alpha^{n-1} - \dots - a_n = 0
$$

by $\alpha^n$ yields

$$
1 - a_1 \alpha^{-1} - a_2 \alpha^{-2} - \dots - a_n \alpha^{-n} = 0\quad.
$$

Substituting $L = \alpha^{-1}$ gives the inverse characteristic equation

$$
1 - a_1 L - a_2 L^2 - \dots - a_n L^n = 0\quad. 
$$

Therefore, the roots $L_i$ of the inverse characteristic equation are the reciprocals of the roots $\alpha_i$ of the characteristic equation,

$$
L_i = \frac{1}{\alpha_i}\quad.
$$

(And as a consequence, the solution of a homogeneous autoregressive difference equation is stable if all roots of its characteristic polynomials are *inside* the unit circle, or equivalently, the roots of its inverse characteristic polynomial are *outside* of the unit circle.)

Comment: "inverse characteristic equation" is not proper. One could say reciprocal characteristic equation instead. Furthermore, the computations you are doing could have been done without replacing the unknown by the eigenvalues. I like using (general convention) $t$ or $z$ as the unknown, and $\alpha_k$ as the coefficients. The way you wrote it may be confusing :)